# deal with an improperly unmounted disk

Tags: mount, umount, exfat

I didn't properly unmount a new external disk which I mounted like:

```
jeremy@jr:~$ sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdc1 /home/jeremy/exfat
FUSE exfat 1.2.3
```

and now I am stuck -

```
jeremy@jr:~$ df -h
df: /home/jeremy/exfat: Transport endpoint is not connected
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           765M  9.5M  756M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       213G  200G  2.1G 100% /
tmpfs           3.8G  165M  3.6G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           765M  116K  765M   1% /run/user/1000
```

I can't go forward (mounting) or backward (unmounting) -

```
jeremy@jr:~$ sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdc1 /home/jeremy/exfat
FUSE exfat 1.2.3
fuse: failed to access mountpoint /home/jeremy/exfat: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

the mtab file looks like

```
jeremy@jr:~$ more /etc/mtab
....
/dev/sdb1 /home/jeremy/exfat fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

my primitive grasp of matters led me to try:

```
jeremy@jr:~$ ls /mnt
sdb1
jeremy@jr:~$ umount /mnt
umount: /mnt: not mounted
jeremy@jr:~$ umount /mnt/sdb1
umount: /mnt/sdb1: not mounted
jeremy@jr:~$ umount /home/jeremy/exfat 
umount: /home/jeremy/exfat: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

since the disk now appears at /sdc1 after i unplugged/replugged it in the vain hopes that that would clear the /etc/mtab entry I tried:

```
jeremy@jr:~$ sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdc1 /home/jeremy/exfat
FUSE exfat 1.2.3
fuse: failed to access mountpoint /home/jeremy/exfat: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

yeesh - this is worse than mating dogs

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo umount -f /home/jeremy/exfat
```

seems to have done the trick, a hint in that direction from the os instead of 'not mounted' would have been great